# Function to generate randomly incrementing number over time

Tags: math, random

I'm trying to make a fake `download count`. It should increment randomly over time. Some download-count-like patterns would be nice.

Is this possible without using a database, or storing a counter anywhere?

My idea is to check the number of seconds that have passed since my app was released. Then just throw that into a formula which spits out the fake download count. Users can request to see the download count at any time.

Is there a math function that increments randomly? I could just pass my `secondsPassed` into there and scale it how I'd like.

Something like this: `getDownloadCount(secondsPassed)`

[image]

Edit: here's an example solution. But it gets worse performance over time.

```
downloadCount = 0
loop secondsPassed/60 times // Loop one more time for every minute passed
  downloadCount += seededRandom(0, 10)
```

Comment: y = sin(x) + x might do something like what you're looking for. not really random though.  also, unless you have a programming question, this is not appropriate for stackoverflow.

Comment: This isn't a complete solution, but you could incorporate the [Prime-counting function *π(x)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) somehow.

Comment: why would you think a database would help?  All computer languages have some sort of random function.  All you have to do is store your accumulated total in a variable, perhaps a static variable, and add the random amount to it.  But we need more context.  Is this even a programming question.

Comment: What language are you using? You can just increment a random number from `1..n` to a variable constantly.

Comment: Or, you could programmatically use the [SO API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) to get the view count on this very question. :)

Comment: "Users can request to see the download count at any time" - So it would be the same for each user or different for each one? Like I mentioned you can do [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/oyodLahw/), but it will be different for each user. If you want it to be the same for each user you need to use a database.

Comment: So you want a "random" number that's guaranteed to be greater than the last "random" number without having to store the last number?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek It should be the same for all users

Comment: @DStanley Pretty much, yup

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar Then you will need a database to store the graph information, that is if it's really random. Or you can just have a random-looking graph with predetermined values.

Comment: Which language are you using? A static variable will "hold" a value for the duration of a runtime. For some systems (C#/IIS) that is the lifetime of the app-pool, for other systems there is a new process for each request so you would need to store the history outside the process somehow. (Database, filestore, etc).

Comment: @Eterm If the server is restarted, I don't want to lose my download count. I don't think the language should be relevant. It'll be PHP though. This does seem to be more of a math question than a programming question.

Comment: If you are after both randomness and consistency with previous generations then this is most definitely a programming question rather than Math. One way to get the same results without storing in a database would be to use a set seed for the random algorithm so the randomly generated sequence is the same every single time.

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar I've amended my answer so that it generates the same random step-sequence every time. As long as you poll the sequence in the same way each time it'll generate the same random looking fake data. Changing the seed will generate a new fake graph.

Comment: Look into a [Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process).

Answer (score 1):

You are after a sequence which always increases by a random amount, depending on how long you last requested the sequence.

This can be done through a random sequence that is always seeded the same.

Then we iterate through the same sequence each time to get the graph.

We need a function that increments our counter, store the new Time and Count and return the count.

Ideally we would model the increases as a poisson process, but a linear one here will do.

```
class Counter {
    private static int counter = 0;
    private static int time = 0;

    private static double rate = 5.0;

    private Random r;

    public Counter(int seed){
        counter = 0;
        r = new Random(seed);
    }

    private int poisson(double rate, int diff){
    // We're gonna cheat here and sample uniformly
        return r.Next(0, (int)Math.Round(rate * diff));
    }

    public int getNext(int t){
        var diff = t - time;
        time = t;
        if (diff <= 0) return counter;

        counter += this.poisson(rate, diff);
        return counter;
    }
}
void Main()
{
    var c = new Counter(1024);
    for(var i = 0; i< 10; i++){
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("||{0}\t|{1}\t||",i,c.getNext(i)));
    }
}
```

This outputs (for example):

```
||t  |hit||
||0  |0  ||
||1  |3  ||
||2  |4  ||
||3  |6  ||
||4  |6  ||
||5  |8  ||
||6  |10  ||
||7  |13  ||
||8  |13  ||
||9  |16  ||
```

Answer (score 1):

Making a fake download count doesn't sound like a nice thing to do. However in designing secure communication protocols, there are legitimate use cases for monotonically growing functions with some randomness in their values.

I am assuming you have:

- A growth model given as a monotonically growing function providing approximate values for the desired function.
- Access to a time stamp, which never decreases.
- Ability to store a constant random seed along with the function definition.
- No way to store any updated data upon the function being queried.

First you decide on a window length, which will control how much randomness will be in the final output. I expect you will want this to be on the order of one hour or a few.

Figure out which window the current time is within. Evaluate the reference function at the start and end of this window. Consider the rectangle given by start and end time of the window as well as min and maximum value given by the reference function. Feed the corners of this rectangle and your constant seed into a PRNG. Use the PRNG to choose a random point within the rectangle. This point will be on the final curve.

Perform the same computation for one of the neighbor windows. Which neighbor window to use depend on whether the first computed point on the curve is to the left or the right of the current time.

Now that you have two points on the curve (which are reproducible and consistent), you will have to iterate the following procedure.

You are given two points on the final curve. Consider the rectangle given by those corners. Feed the corners and your constant seed into a PRNG. Use that PRNG to chose a random point within the rectangle. This point will be on the final curve. Discard one of the outer points, which is no longer needed.

Since the Y-values are restricted to integers, this procedure will eventually terminate once your two points on the curve have identical Y-coordinate, and you will know, that the function has to be constant between those two points.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a [Morris Counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_counting_algorithm#Algorithm).

It works like this: start off by setting the counter to 1. Each time you want to increase the count (which could be every iteration of some loop or every time an event happens, but does not need to be determined randomly), then you do a random procedure to determine the effect it has on the counter.

It can have possibly no effect, or it can have the effect of raising the order of magnitude of the count. The probability is based on whether or not n successive fair coin flips all turn up heads, where n is the number of bits needed to encode the current counter value in binary. As a result, once the counter has gotten pretty high, it's very hard to make it go even higher (the state of the counter models a phenomenon where by you are already way overestimating the count, so now you need lots of nothing-happens events to compensate, making the count more accurate).

This is used as a cheap way to store an approximate count of a very large collection, but there's no reason why you can't use it as your randomly increasing counter device.

If you want better accuracy, or you want the count outputs to be more "normal" numbers instead of always powers of 2, then you can just create several Morris Counters, and at each step average together the set of current counts across them all.

Answer (score 0):

For some deterministic function `f`, (perhaps `f(x) = x`, or if your fake app is REALLY awesome `f(x) = 2^x`), and a random function `r` which outputs random number that's sometimes negative and sometimes positive.

Your graphing function `g` could be:

`g(x) = f(x) + r`

EDIT

How about this: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26391/is-there-a-family-of-monotonically-non-decreasing-noise-functions

Comment: Sometimes the download count would go down with this. If I kept refreshing the count it'd look insane.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not "random" but you could use `A*(X/B + SIN(X/B))` (scaled by some number) to introduce *some* noise.  You can adjust A and B to change the scale of the result and how often the "noise" cycles.

Really, any periodic function that has a first derivative within some bounds could work.

Answer (score 0):

as quick solution you can use something like this (code in java):

```
static long f(final int x) {
    long r = 0; // initial counter
    long n = 36969L; // seed
    for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        n = 69069L * n + 1234567L; // generate Ith random number
        r += (n & 0xf); // add random number to counter
    }
    return r;
}
```

by playing with numbers `36969L` and `0xf` you can achieve different results

numbers `69069L` and `1234567L` are from standard [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)

the main idea - create simple random, with the same seed and for every passed x (number of seconds) replay random additions to counter

Answer (score 0):

A good model for random events like downloads is the Poisson distribution. You need to estimate the average number of downloads in a given time period (hour, say) and then invert the Poisson distribution to get the number of downloads in a time period given a uniformly distributed random number. For extra realism you can vary the average according to time of day, time of week, etc. Sample algorithms are available at http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Generating_Poisson-distributed_random_variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript implementation of a "fake" download-counter that appears the same to everyone. This always returns the same results for everyone each time and doesn't require database or files to do that. It also gracefully handles the case where you don't ask for new data at the same time, it will still look natural next time you request a day.
[image]
https://jsfiddle.net/Lru1tenL/1/

```
Counter = {
        time:Date.now(),
        count:0,
        rate:0.45
    };

Counter.seed = function(seed, startTime)
{
    this.time = startTime,
    this.count = 0,
    this.prng = new Math.seedrandom(seed);
    this.prng.getRandomInt = function(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(this() * (max - min)) + min;
    };
};

Counter.getNext = function(t){

    var diff = t - this.time;
    console.log(diff);


    if(diff <= 0) return this.count;

    this.time = t;
    var max = Math.ceil(diff/100 * this.rate);

    console.log("max: " + max);
    this.count += this.prng.getRandomInt(0,max);
    return this.count;
};

var results = [];

var today = Date.now();

Counter.seed("My Random Seed", today);


for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if(i === 4)
    {
        results.push(null);
    } else {
        var future = today +  86400000 * i;
        results.push(Counter.getNext(future));
    }
}

console.log(results);

    var data = {
    labels: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday","Sunday"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: results
        }

    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
```

Is the javascript. It creates a counter object that increments when requested based on the time of the previous value asked for. The repeatability comes through a thirdparty library "seedrandom" and the chart is drawn using chartjs.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/seedrandom/2.4.0/seedrandom.min.js">
</script>
<body>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Unix timestamp. Something like:

```
Downloads = constant + ( unix time / another constant )
```

You can vary both constants to get a reasonable number.

P.S: Thats if you want a linear function, otherwise you can do:

```
Downloads = (unix time) ^ constant
```

and so on.

Comment: This is too linear though

Comment: My mistake. I edited the answer. I meant use the unix time as a variable.

Comment: Now it's too exponential :p The download count would eventually get way too high